# why i get Error running 'JBoss 11.0.0.Final': Unable to open debugger port (127.0.0.1:56884): java.net.SocketException "socket closed"?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jakarta-ee, web-deployment, wildfly-11

I use latest intellij idea ultimate with wildfly 11 and i develop web application with maven and java 8.
when i run debug i get following error.

**Error running 'JBoss 11.0.0.Final': Unable to open debugger port (127.0.0.1:56884): java.net.SocketException "socket closed"**

when i run application i get

**Error running 'JBoss 11.0.0.Final': Address 127.0.0.1:9990 is already in use**

iI did changed the port to 9991 in standalone.xml and got the following error:

**Application Server was not connected before run configuration stop, reason: Unable to ping server at localhost:8080**

Does any one know what am i missing?

Comment: Do you override/force WildFly JVM options somehow? Try with the vanilla server installation and startup scripts.

Comment: I didn't change any thing such as JVM options.
What do you means by Try with the vanilla server installation and startup scripts.?

Comment: Is the server already running before you start it in IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: not that i know. I don't think so. i test it in browsers on the port 8080

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the logs attached: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085.

Comment: Which log? where is the place of such a log?. i get only popup with this error .

Comment: idea.log, the link provides the details.